# how to convert long value to string without changing its content?

Tags: c++, c

hi a have a pointer variable with value 0x6859510364 ,
 i have to convert it in to string wihtout changing its value. 
please can anyone help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want the address or the contents of that address?

Comment: Whatever the answer, there are plenty of question such like this one already answered. Please search them.

Comment: You need to decide whether you're doing this in C or C++ - they are two different languages.

Comment: That value is over 32bit, but you don't have the 0 prefixes for 64bit.

Comment: OK you want content. So what type of variable does this point to?

Comment: it pointing unknow type ... actually it contains memory address

Answer (score 1):

you can always use a `std::ostringstream`, like

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string toString( void* p )
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << p;
    return stream.str();
}
```

note: if it is a function pointer then it's not formally convertible to `void*`, and then you have to adjust signature of function above to take your pointer type.

you may also have to add `const` etc.

instead of writing such functions yourself you can use `boost::lexical_cast`, from the Boost library.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

```
long* number;//=0x6859510364;
TCHAR str[20];
_ltot_s(*number, str, 16);
```

Comment: hey IAZ plz can u tell me which file should be included.

Comment: i mean which heder file _ltot_s in defined